# Redirect to seo url with different language in opencart 2

Tags: php, url, opencart, opencart2.x

I have a problem when I change the language on my site, so if I am in `product/category` page and I change the language, I will redirect to error page because the seo url is different between the different language,

**For example:** I have the `product/category` page with seo url "camere" in italian and "rooms" in english, if I change the language, the url will be this : `camere?_route_=camere` I know that the problem is in `catalog/controller/common/language.php` file, but i don't know how I can resolve it. Someone can help me?

My site: http://luca.orkestra.eu

Comment: Is your site online? which url?

Comment: yes it is: http://luca.orkestra.eu/ is the site that i use to learn web develop.